# Remove a SPID after LINQ in Entity Framework

Tags: linq, entity-framework, spid

I have an application where I use Entity Framework to interact with a MS SQL database.  In it I make calls to the Dbcontext inside using blocks.  The problem that I'm having is that, even after the Dbcontext has been disposed of, the SPID sits there with a status of sleeping until the application exits.  How would I remove these hanging SPIDs?

Comment: When used with Sql Server, Entity Framework uses the Connection Pooling provided by the .NET Provider, which means that connections are held in a pool by the process, and reallocated as needed. You don't want to turn off connection pooling - it significantly enhances performance.

Comment: Is there a way to release those connections quicker?

Comment: You might be able to find a way to reduce the [idle timeout (seems 4-8 minutes as per here)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca(v=vs.110).aspx) but I would personally leave it alone - Connection pooling significantly improves your app performance and has been around for ages. Also note that there isn't necessarily a correlation between DbContext lifespan and a connection - DbContext will grab a connection from the pool and release it ASAP. You can check when released via tracing `sp_reset_connection`

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't want to, but this should work:

```
((SqlConnection)dbContext.Database.Connection).ClearAllPools();
```

As mentioned above, this can and will negatively impact the performance of your application (and perhaps other applications).  Perhaps the real question might be, why do you want to remove the SPID?

You could also add `Pooling=false` to the connection string which should prevent the application from using the Connection Pool at all.  Depending on your application, this may or may not affect performance greatly.